# Custom headers are being stripped out when sent to API gateaway AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-headers, aws-api-gateway

so I'm trying to access some custom headers from my Post request in my Lambda function.

When i try to do some http mapping or body mapping in API gateway it doesn't work or just doesn't let me. I have an example of when it doesn't let me.

The header I'm using are called "php-auth-user".

[image: error]

I've also tried the mapping template with the following inside :

```
{
"method": "$context.httpMethod",
"body" : $input.json('$'),
"headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "Mapped from" value as (in single quotes) to avoid the error on the console -

> 'method.request.header.php-auth-user'

Also, make sure the header 'php-auth-user' is added in the list of headers under "Method Request" tab as well.

Comment: I've added both in the "Mapped from" field and the "Method Request" list of headers and its still not passing the custom header through. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @hilangpd It could be a mapping template issue. Try using the "Method request passthrough" mapping template. This template will basically forward all headers, query strings and other params as it is from the request to Lambda. If that doesn't work too, probably share the curl command you are using to invoke the API.